# SQL case two conditions two columns

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

I have the data as follow:

---

"Table" computer data

```
date       |    property   |    computer code
----------      --------        -----------
20160131   |   companyA   |     256584
20160131   |   companyB   |     987451
```

to e.t.c

```
20171020   |   companyA   |     157489
```

I want to count the number of computer in each company after 2017-Sep, so I use:

```
select
 computer data

 , count (case computer code when property='companyA' and date='20171001' then 1 else 0 end) as CMAnumber
 , count (case computer code when property='companyB' and date='20171001' then 1 else 0 end) as CMBnumber

from
[data]

group by
computer data

order by
computer data
```

---

but it not work...
please help!!

I use SQL server 2014 Management Studio. and the data base from company system

and I want to show it like

```
date |  CMAnumber | CMBnumber

20171001 |  200   |  210

20171002 |  230   |  207
```

ETC

sorry about that I am a fresh on SQL T.T

Comment: Care to elaborate about "but it not work"? Are you getting an error? The wrong results?

Comment: `COUNT()` counts all non-null values, i.e. both 1 and 0 are counted. Do `SUM()` instead.

Comment: or use COUNT() to count, just feed it NULLS when that is needed

Comment: Are you getting an error or incorrect results? If error: ***What is the error message?*** If incorrect results: The query in your question should be producing an error, so you ***have given the wrong query***. (And don't expect useful help if you provide the ***wrong*** information.)

Comment: I got Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3 Incorrect syntax near '='

Comment: and I don't know the code is correct or not for the performance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use `CASE` for count some conditions, and if you choose `COUNT` function for it, else part of the case should be `NULL`, otherwise, it counts else condition too. Or you should use SUM instead of COUNT. I updated the script for COUNT function.

And your case using wrong, I corrected it too.

```
SELECT
 [computer data]
 , count (case when property='companyA' and date >= '20171001' then 1 end) as CMAnumber
 , count (case when property='companyB' and date >= '20171001' then 1 end) as CMBnumber
from
    [data]
where
    date >= '20171001'
group by
    [computer data]
order by
    [computer data]
```

Comment: the date can't be sort after Oct-2017, the data shown from Jan-2011 and all the number be 0

Comment: and I have one more question, all the date is shown on the table

Comment: like 20110101 is shown with 0 and 0.   unit 20171001 is shown 200 210 (correct data). how can I sort the date only show 20171001 for the start

Comment: If you have the date column in the select part of the query, you can add it to order by too.

Answer (score 2):

You are mixing two `case` forms.

The serached form has a condition after the `when`:

```
CASE WHEN <condition> ..
```

The simple form has it split: a common operand between `case` and `when` and expressions after the `when`. It implies an equals comparision:

```
CASE <common operand> WHEN <expression> ...
```

More about case: http://modern-sql.com/feature/case

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
SELECT property , COUNT(*)
  FROM [data]
 WHERE DATE > '20170930'
GROUP BY property ;
```

Comment: @CraigYoung, I did and, if the PO is interested only in a collection of companies (like he wrote), he can simply add a `AND property IN (...)`. I see no reason to make things complex when they can be very simple. The whole `case` construct is not needed at all. The only this is  a PIVOT of the answer, which could be arranged by a simple SELECT wrapping the one I suggested.

Comment: OP is quite clearly trying to get 2 separate counts for 2 different companies. Your answer comes nowhere near doing that. Your answer also doesn't do anything to address either of the 2 specific problems OP is likely facing.

Comment: @CraigYoung, SO is aimed to either give a working solution or suggest a different way of thinking. What the OP needs can be quite easily achieved by adding a second `GROUP BY` (date) and pivoting the result to get the counts. In my mind, I consider the situation in which he does not need only two companies but a variable number of companies, in which case the presented SELECT (with the case) in the question and the marked answer would become quite ... **a nightmare(!)**. Having said that, your point is clear as it is mine. Let's agree that we disagree. Deal?

Answer (score 0):

You can do a combination of subQuery and group by

```
select property,count(*) from (select * from [computer data] where date > '20170930') group by property
```

Comment: I got

Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near '='.

Comment: Check whether you table name and column names are correct